# Does SQL*Loader have any functionality that allows for customizing the log file?

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

I have been asked to create a system for allowing third party companies to dump data into several of our tables. These third parties provide csv files on a periodic basis, and after doing some research it seemed like Oracle themselves had a standard tool for doing so, "sqlldr". I've since gotten it working to an acceptable degree, and we have a job scheduled to run that script once a day.

But one of the third parties supplies really dirty data, of the sort where I can't expect it to always load every row/record (looking like up to about 8% will fail). My boss asked me to forward "all output" from the first few tests to him, and like a moron I also sent the log file.

He has asked that this "report" be modified to include those exceptions that aren't unique constraints along with the line in the input file that caused the exception.

This means that I need data from the log file, but also from the (I believe) reject file in a single document. Rather than write a convoluted shell script to combine those two, does SQL*Loader itself allow any customization that might achieve the same thing? I've read through the Oracle documentation and haven't found anything that suggests this, but I've also learned not to trust it entirely either.

Is this possible? Ideally, the solution would allow me to add values to the reject file that don't exist in the original input file, but I'm also interested in any customization of the log file or reject file.

Comment: No, it doesn't.  Could you load all your data into a staging table with `varchar2(4000)` columns (or, even better, use an external table with all `varchar2(4000)` columns) and then have a process that moves the data from the staging table to the real table that logs rejections (say with DML error logging)?  Then it would be relatively easy to produce a report of whatever you'd like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

I was going to stop there, but you can define the *name* of the log file, which might help with issue. Most automation with SQL*Loader involves wrapping it within shell scripts; aka "roll your own."